# How to get header from InvocationBuilder object from request in JUnit 5 test

Tags: java, junit, request, jersey, request-headers

I want to test a method which is adding a header in a request to outside public API.

The method looks like:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
class ProductsFacadeImpl implements ProductsFacade {

  private NutritionixHeader nutritionixHeader;

  @Override
  public Invocation.Builder prepareHeaderForApiCall(String query) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget =
        client.target("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=" + query);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    invocationBuilder.header("x-app-id", nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppId());
    invocationBuilder.header("x-app-key", nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppKey());
    return invocationBuilder;
  }
}
```

new version method for EDIT purpose:

```
  @Override
  public Invocation prepareHeaderForApiCall(String query) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget =
        client.target("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=" + query);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    invocationBuilder.header("x-app-id", nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppId());
    invocationBuilder.header("x-app-key", nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppKey());
    return invocationBuilder.buildGet();
  }
```

In my JUnit 5 test, I want to check if my header contains two objects which are required by public API. It's:

```
"x-app-id"
```

and

```
"x-app-key"
```

My test looks like:

```
@Test
  void prepareHeaderForApiCall() {
    var query = "query";

    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppId()).willReturn(appId);
    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppKey()).willReturn(appKey);

    Invocation.Builder builder = productsFacade.prepareHeaderForApiCall(query);

    builder.get();

    assertEquals(appId, builder.get().getHeaders().entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("x-app-id")).map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst().orElse(null));

  }
```

The problem is that the method

```
getHeaders()
```

in my stream does not contain headers which I added and it looks like:

[image]

I want to know how I can get a header params objects which are placed in a requestContext object as a header objects like below:

[image]

EDIT:

I found one interesting thing with debugger and evaluate expression in IntelliJ, namely:

[image]

with this above expression, I can find out my two added headers but I cannot use the same expression in a code.

I will be grateful for a suggestion about how to reach a goal by getting headers object from the requestContext object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following:

1) `builder.get().getMetadata()`

2) `builder.get().getStringHeaders()`

3) if previous two fail
`((ClientResponse)ReflectionTestUtils.getField(builder.get(), "context")).getHeaders()`

Comment: It did not bring a desirable effect because of these two methods bases on a method getHeaders(). On the first screen we can see that there are x-app-id and x-app-key not present after getHeaders(), getMetadata() or getStringHeaders() usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
Field requestContextField = JerseyInvocation.Builder.class.getDeclaredField("requestContext");
requestContextField.setAccessible(true);
ClientRequest clientRequest = (ClientRequest)requestContextField.get(invocationBuilder);
MultivaluedMap<String, Object> actualHeaders = clientRequest.getHeaders();
```